# How to color function call in Vim syntax highlighting

Tags: vim, vim-syntax-highlighting

I'm new to Vim and curious how to highlight a function call after the function has been defined. As an [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBkaH.jpg), in the SublimeText version, totalForArray is green when it is defined, as well as when it is called on line 12. This is what my Vim looks like [imgur.com/q2WMQ4d](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vY4Od.jpg), and I'm wondering how to make totalForArray highlighted when it's called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vim's syntax parsing usually only colors the function *definition*, because that one is easy to locate with a regular expression. For function *calls*, it would have to maintain a list of detected functions.

There are plugins that extend syntax highlighting with such a list, usually taken from the *tags database*. For example, the [easytags.vim plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3114) performs automatic tags updates and can highlight those via the `:HighlightTags` command.

Comment: I've used a `\<\w\+(` in the past with some success. May become slow on big files, but does the trick.

Comment: @Ingo-Karkat thanks, I downloaded the easytags plugin (along with vim-misc and exuberant ctags) and I can now jump to function definitions but unfortunately I don't think the syntax highlighting works on Javascript files, which is what I spend most of my time with

Comment: @Vitor Where do I put in `\<\w\+(`?

Comment: Try adding the following to your vimrc: `syn match myFunction "\<\w\+\ze("`. @IngoKarkat could you please review this suggestion? Thx

Comment: @Vitor: Yes, that would work (in most cases, unless obscured by another syntax group). It's different from my answer, though, because it'll highlight _all_ functions, regardless of known or not.

Answer (score 5):

An improvement on Vitor's regex matching.
This will highlight nested function calls while respecting highlighting for keywords like `while`, `if`, `for`, etc... and also allows for whitespace between function name and parenthesis
e.g. `myFunction (int argc) { ... }`

```
syn match dFunction "\zs\(\k\w*\)*\s*\ze("
hi link dFunction Function
```

Comment: I tried putting these in my `.vimrc` but they didn't work there, so I moved them to: `.vim/after/syntax/go.vim` (`go.vim` because I am using the Go language if you are using some other language use the appropriate filename like `c.vim` or `cpp.vim`)

Answer (score 2):

As a simpler alternative to what was proposed by @Ingo, you can also define a syntax to match any keyword that is directly followed by a parentheses:

```
syn match jsFunction "\<\k\+\ze("
hi link jsFunction Function
```

Searching in github I was also able to find the [vim-javascript](https://github.com/pangloss/vim-javascript) plugin, which appears to have various extensions to the default Javascript syntax included in Vim. In particular, it contains the following syntax definition:

```
syntax match jsFuncCall /\k\+\%(\s*(\)\@=/
```

This will implement the same syntax highlight I described before, but by using this plugin you might also benefit from other improvements that are included in it.